# Slicing in python in a csv

Tags: python, csv, slice

I have a question about slicing in python. I'm working with a csv file and I want to get only the first value in row that corresponds with another value, which the user will specify. For example, my csv file looks like this:

```
| Date | Wind (mph) |
|------|------------|
| 20   | W 3        |
| 20   | W 3        |
| 20   | Vrbl 5     |
| 19   | Vrbl 7     |
| 19   | W 7        |
```

I want to get only the first wind direction value that corresponds with the date entered. From there, I want to get only the first letter. For example, if I requested the date of the 20th, I want wind = w. I think I need to slice the row, but I can't figure out where.

```
import csv
date = (raw_input("Please enter a date within the past three days (format: for 12/2/15, enter '02'): "))
with open('wind.csv', 'rb') as csvfile_wind:
    reader3 = csv.reader(csvfile_wind)
    for row in reader3: 
        if(row[0]) == date:
            wind = (row[1])
            print wind
```

Comment: Not super familiar with the `csv` library, so bear with me.  Is the code above printing "W 3" and you want it to print only "W"?  Also, do you want to handle multiple letters in the wind direction? e.g. "NW"?

Comment: I suggest you to check the pandas library that is very helpful when working with csv and similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to split it.
You could just do

```
if(row[0]) == date:
            wind = row[1][0]
            print wind
```

to print only the first character at index [0] of the string in row[1]

Answer (score 0):

What is the delimiter in the csv file?
Anyway, I assume that

```
row[1].split(" ")[0]
```

would do the trick.

E.g.,

```
In [1]: "w 3".split(" ")[0]
Out[1]: 'w'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct.

Please, try to add some args `csv.reader(csvfile_wind, dialect='excel-tab', delimiter=';')`

You can also print row as well.
If row have splited you can see something like [20, 'some string']

And you don't need brackets:

```
if row[0] == date:
   wind = row[1]
   print wind
```